# How to change the [[source]] for the Pipfile for better usage of pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

The default `[[source]]` for Pipfile is

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```

Now I just want to change it to `url = "https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple/"`, do I need to change the name at the same time?

If yes, then what is the name rule?  *(or is it okay for me to go simply without this "name"?)*

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this page](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/docs/advanced.rst), section Specifying Indexes.

The name is some field you define arbitrary and use with the index key to specify where a package should come from.

Comment: link no longer works...